# Cannt able to find Element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My coding not find element. Pls anyone help me to come out of my mistake.

**Testcase**

```
    @Test 
public void main() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Before sign in action execution");
    SignIn_Action.Execute(iTestCaseRow);
}
```

**SignIn_Action**

```
    public class SignIn_Action{
       public static void Execute(int iTestCaseRow) throws Exception{
           // Fetch user name from Excel
           String sUserName = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.col_UserName);
           System.out.println("User Name read from --> "+ sUserName);
           // Fetch password from Excel
           String sPassword = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.col_Password);
           System.out.println("Password read from excel --> "+ sPassword);
           LoginPageObjects.txtbx_username().sendKeys(sUserName);
           LoginPageObjects.txtbx_password().sendKeys(sPassword);
           LoginPageObjects.btn_login().click();
   }
```

**LoginPageObject class**

```
    public class LoginPageObjects extends BaseClass {
    private static WebElement element = null; 
    public LoginPageObjects(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

     public static WebElement txtbx_username(){  
        try {       
        WebElement element = null;          
        System.out.println("Inside txtbx_username method");      
        element = driver.findElement(By.name("first_name"));        
        System.out.println("Fetched element name is : "+element);    
        Log.info("Username text box found");
        }catch (Exception e){        
            Log.error("UserName text box is not found on the Login Page");
            throw(e);
            } 
        return element;
        }
}
}
```

**BaseClass**

```
    public class BaseClass {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static boolean bResult;
    public  BaseClass(WebDriver driver){
        BaseClass.driver = driver;
        BaseClass.bResult = true;
    }
}
```

My problem is in the below code

```
element = driver.findElement(By.name("first_name"));
```

This code is not find element and it shows below error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pageObjects.LoginPageObjects.txtbx_username(LoginPageObjects.java:27)
```

Comment: Add the relevant html.

Comment: <input name="first_name" ng-model="UserName" class="form-control floatLabel ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" my-float-text="" type="text">

Comment: IMO, this is happening due to conflicting declaration of `element`. Once you declared `private static WebElement element = null;` next again `WebElement element = null;`